# Primefaces :radioButton inside a ui:repeat

Tags: layout, radio-button, primefaces, uirepeat

This is my xhtml code :

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

  <h:head>
    <title>Custom Radio Test</title>
  </h:head>

  <h:body>

    <h:form id="mF" >

      <p:selectOneRadio id="ITRadioGrp" value="#{testBean.radioSelectedValue}" layout="custom">
        <f:selectItems value="#{testBean.selectItems}" />
      </p:selectOneRadio>

      <h:panelGrid columns="1">

        <ui:repeat id="vBGOF" value="#{testBean.groupOfFlights}" var="aFlight" varStatus="gofIndex">
          <p:radioButton for="ITRadioGrp" itemIndex="#{gofIndex.index}"/> #{aFlight}
        </ui:repeat>

      </h:panelGrid>

    </h:form>

  </h:body>

</html>
```

and this is the managed bean :

```
    package com.modern;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;
import java.util.*;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class TestBean {

  private String radioSelectedValue;
  private String[] groupOfFlights;
  private List selectItems;

  public TestBean() {
    groupOfFlights = new String[]{"FlightOne", "FlightTwo", "FlightThree"};
  }

  public String[] getGroupOfFlights() {
    return groupOfFlights;
  }

  public void setGroupOfFlights(String[] groupOfFlights) {
    this.groupOfFlights = groupOfFlights;
  }

  public String getRadioSelectedValue() {
    return radioSelectedValue;
  }

  public void setRadioSelectedValue(String radioSelectedValue) {
    this.radioSelectedValue = radioSelectedValue;
  }

  // modified
  public List getSelectItems() {
    try {
      if (selectItems == null || selectItems.isEmpty()) {
        selectItems = new ArrayList();
        for (int g = 0; g < 3; g++) {
          SelectItem option = new SelectItem(g, "flight" + (g + 1)); // value, label
          selectItems.add(option);
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(this.getClass().getName() + "] EXCEPTION " + e.toString());
    }
    return selectItems;
  }

  public void setSelectItems(List selectItems) {
    this.selectItems = selectItems;
  }
}
```

I always get the same error :

**Cannot find component 'mF:ITRadioGrp' in view.**

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component 'mF:ITRadioGrp' in view.
    at org.primefaces.component.radiobutton.RadioButtonRenderer.findSelectOneRadio(RadioButtonRenderer.java:144)
    at org.primefaces.component.radiobutton.RadioButtonRenderer.encodeEnd(RadioButtonRenderer.java:35)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1763)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.RepeatRenderer.encodeChildren(RepeatRenderer.java:104)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.process(UIRepeat.java:513)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.encodeChildren(UIRepeat.java:974)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1756)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1756)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:401)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
```

I've tried to change the "for" attribute in

```
<p:radioButton for="mF:ITRadioGrp" itemIndex="#{gofIndex.index}"/> #{aFlight}
```

to (i checked the HTML source deleting the layout=custom" in p:selectOneRadio) :

1. mF:ITRadioGrp
2. ITRadioGrp
3. mF:ITRadioGrp:0
4. mF:ITRadioGrp:1 ...

but always same error!!
where i'm wrong???
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a colon as prefix in order to address the `p:selectOneRadio` beginning from the view root:

```html
<p:radioButton for=":mF:ITRadioGrp" itemIndex="#{gofIndex.index}"/>
```

If this does not work, look into the html source of your page in browser and find the correct client id for the `p:selectOneRadio`. Use this id in your `for` attribute.