# JSF & Primefaces: Component ID just won't get found

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I keep receiving the same exception again and again. Comparing exception and hmtl-output without *for="#{choiceRadio.clientId}"* seems to tell me that binding works. But it just doesn't and I feel like I am missing something huge.

The Code:

```
    <p:selectOneRadio binding="#{choiceRadio}" value="#" layout="custom">
        <f:selectItems value="#" />
    </p:selectOneRadio>

    <h:panelGrid columns="1">
        <ui:repeat var='choice' value='#{item.items3}'>
            <p:radioButton for="#{choiceRadio.clientId}" />#{choice.name}
        </ui:repeat>
    </h:panelGrid>

</h:form>
```

The Exception:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot find component 'j_idt34:0:j_idt36:2:j_idt46:j_idt82' in view.
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
    org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
root cause

javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component 'j_idt34:0:j_idt36:2:j_idt46:j_idt82' in view.
    org.primefaces.component.radiobutton.RadioButtonRenderer.findSelectOneRadio(RadioButtonRenderer.java:126)
    org.primefaces.component.radiobutton.RadioButtonRenderer.encodeEnd(RadioButtonRenderer.java:35)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.component.RepeatRenderer.encodeChildren(RepeatRenderer.java:104)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.process(UIRepeat.java:523)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.encodeChildren(UIRepeat.java:984)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:105)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:105)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    org.primefaces.component.lightbox.LightBoxRenderer.encodeMarkup(LightBoxRenderer.java:52)
    org.primefaces.component.lightbox.LightBoxRenderer.encodeEnd(LightBoxRenderer.java:32)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:59)
    org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:43)
    org.primefaces.component.outputpanel.OutputPanelRenderer.encodeEnd(OutputPanelRenderer.java:46)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.component.RepeatRenderer.encodeChildren(RepeatRenderer.java:104)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.process(UIRepeat.java:523)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.encodeChildren(UIRepeat.java:984)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:105)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:55)
    org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:43)
    org.primefaces.component.outputpanel.OutputPanelRenderer.encodeEnd(OutputPanelRenderer.java:46)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.component.RepeatRenderer.encodeChildren(RepeatRenderer.java:104)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.process(UIRepeat.java:523)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.encodeChildren(UIRepeat.java:984)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final logs.

JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final
```

Without ui:repeat I don't get any exception but without ui:repeat I do not have any content either:

```
    <p:selectOneRadio  id="myRadio" value="#{cartBean.selectedChoice}" layout="custom">
        <f:selectItems value="#{item.items3}" />
    </p:selectOneRadio>

    <h:panelGrid columns="1">

            <p:radioButton for="myRadio" value="hh" itemIndex="0"/>

    </h:panelGrid>

</h:form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier

Comment: That's absolutely possible. It was one of the questions/answers I read before. Maybe I didn't really understand as it could not help me in practise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` attribute of the `radioButton` must be the `id` of the `selectOneRadio` it refers to.

Add an `id` to your `selectOneRadio` and refer to it in the button:

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="myRadio" binding="#{choiceRadio}" value="#" layout="custom">
    <f:selectItems value="#" />
</p:selectOneRadio>

<h:panelGrid columns="1">
    <ui:repeat var='choice' value='#{item.items3}'>
        <p:radioButton for="myRadio" />#{choice.name}
    </ui:repeat>
</h:panelGrid>
```

**EDIT**

You might need to prepend the ids of all `NamingContainer`s right from `ViewRoot` before the element `id`, like: `for="form_id:myRadio"`.

When in doubt what the exact absolute `id` of an element might be, look at it in FireBug (Firefox) or developer tools (Chrome) or search for its given `id` (in this case "myRadio") in the html output source and skip possible numbers in-between.

So this

`id="iterateCategories:0:iterateItems:2:lightForm:radioForm"`

would become

`iterateCategories:iterateItems:lightForm:radioForm`

as your absolute id.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but doing this it is quite similar _javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot find component 'myRadio' in view._ That's where I started...

Comment: @Lester - then you need to prepend the form id as well - I have added some details to the answer

Comment: the ids from generated html (without p:radiobutton and thus without exception) is: form id="j_idt34:0:j_idt36:2:form_id
<span id="j_idt34:0:j_idt36:2:form_id:myRadio"></span><script id="j_idt34:0:j_idt36:2:form_id:myRadio_s" 
But it wont work with those ids either... :(

Comment: @Lester I'm afraid I'll have to resort semi-wild guessing then - the Ids look right. have you tried it without the <ui:repeat> and with the itemIndex attribute? - if this still does not work, then i must resign :( sorry

Comment: Without ui:repeat an with itemIndex I get no exception but I lack any content.  
Here someone made to use ui:repeat with radiobutton but I just can't see, what I do different and why it doesn't work for me: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803344/primefaces-radiobutton-inside-a-uirepeat)  
Actually I tried to solve the ID/binding problem this way: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168302/jsf-component-binding-without-bean-property/8168427#8168427)  
But it just won't work...

Comment: Thanks for your help, kostja. I just edited your answer a bit to fully solve my problem.  Because of me not posting my full code, you could not know that one (actually two) of the preceding NamingContainers was a `ui:repeat`which seems to produce an additional number for the id in the html source that must not be adopted into absolute id of successive elements.